# SagePaySuite version PRO_4.0.1 - An error occurred: Please specify a shipping method

Tags: magento, opayo

I'm getting the error below after upgrading to Magento-1.9.2.2 and SagePaySuite PRO-4.0.1.

```
2015-11-18 13:58:04.000000 (1447855084.97) DEBUG: Array
(
    [_session_validator_data] => Array
        (
            [remote_addr] => 195.170.169.14
            [http_via] =>
            [http_x_forwarded_for] =>
            [http_user_agent] => SagePay-Notifier/1.0
        )

    [euro_payment_is_pending] =>
    [vps_tx_id] => {842B4FB4-D4BB-314E-81E3-CCF5B91ED666}
    [tx_auth_no] => 1460340131
    [trn_done_status] =>
    [trnh_data] => a:20:{s:7:"storeid";s:1:"1";s:3:"qid";s:4:"6367";s:12:"VendorTxCode";s:29:"100002452-2015-11-18-13-56-44";s:7:"VPSTxId";s:38:"{842B4FB4-D4BB-314E-81E3-CCF5B91ED666}";s:6:"Status";s:2:"OK";s:12:"StatusDetail";s:40:"0000 : The Authorisation was Successful.";s:8:"TxAuthNo";s:10:"1460340131";s:6:"AVSCV2";s:24:"SECURITY CODE MATCH ONLY";s:13:"AddressResult";s:10:"NOTCHECKED";s:14:"PostCodeResult";s:10:"NOTCHECKED";s:9:"CV2Result";s:7:"MATCHED";s:7:"GiftAid";s:1:"0";s:14:"3DSecureStatus";s:2:"OK";s:4:"CAVV";s:28:"jCanalFk/1SoCBAAAAicCZIAAAA=";s:8:"CardType";s:2:"MC";s:11:"Last4Digits";s:4:"9956";s:11:"DeclineCode";s:2:"00";s:10:"ExpiryDate";s:4:"1018";s:12:"BankAuthCode";s:6:"T28346";s:16:"CustomStatusCode";N;}
    [fail_status] => An error occurred: Please specify a shipping method.
)
```

The issue pasted above only occurs with **Pay with Credit / Debit card payment method** and also i'm getting `MAGE_ERROR` in Admin > Sales > Order [SagePay Status column]